# Source Code Outline Window for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

For Visual Studio 2008 there is the small but great addin "**Source Outliner**" on **Codeplex** (http://sourcecodeoutliner.codeplex.com).

Does anybody know, if there is an equivalent tool for Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: I'm looking for the same extension for VS2010

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a [Solution Navigator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/07/20/solution-navigator-blog-post.aspx) in the [Productivity Tools for Visual Studio extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) that seems like it does much the same thing.

Comment: I know the Solution Navigator, but I think the Source Outliner is more comfortable, because it always shows the outline of the activated class file.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Solution Navigator of Productivity Power Tools

Answer (score 0):

You can install DPack and use its [Code Browser](http://www.usysware.com/dpack/CodeBrowser.aspx) feature.