# how to see public interface of the class?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How can I check public interface of a class in Visual Studio to understand what really class can do?
In Eclipse I can use "Outline" pane for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can refer at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy6s2t6h.aspx)

Otherwise you just need to right click on the class name in the interface and choose "**Go to definition**".

Comment: yes "Class View" is something I can use. Unfortanately this view doesn't syncronize with the file currently opened in editor

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565971/source-code-outline-window-for-visual-studio-2010)

Productivity Power Tools Solutions Explorer should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Right click under the interface name and "Go to definition"